# Laravel 5.5 Send the users email address with the reset link or get the email address of user by token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

In Password Reset page user needs to type their email, we feel its unwanted and think of removing it.

so i can get the token from the url,

```
www.example.com/password/reset/c1ac740d8b1d8674995145577152216e0bb38091f572fd8f040d0cccd293a637.
```

but checking in database its different what is in url and stored in database and im using laravel 5.5.

Learned something from google they are again hashing these token and saving it in db.

so im having 2 ways,

1) How can i get the email address from the token?
2) Else how can i send the email address with the url while sending reset link email  like this `(www.example.com/password/reset/c1ac740d8b1d8674995145577152216e0bb38091f572fd8f040d0cccd293a637/yourmail@gmail.com)`

FYI: All i am using is native, it has $actionUrl only.

Comment: In password reset, if user doesn't type their email, how do you determine whose password to reset?
I use use [hashids](http://hashids.org/php/) for this. I use it to encrypt and decrypt user ID based on their email address.

Comment: You can use reset password token to identify user.